# Symfony 2, Custom Form Widgets For Single inputs?

Tags: forms, symfony

UPDATE/EDIT

This is what I have done, but for some reason its not working. So the services is as follows,

```
clearfix.extended_type:
    class: Bundle\Form\ClearfixExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType }
```

Now I am sure this is wrong, I have not used services much and still trying to get my head around them.

I ave also built the class, see answer below for anyone else reading this, with the right namespace.

I have also done the following to the block,

```
{%- block form_row -%}
  <div class="other classes here {% if clearfix %}clearfix"{% else %}"{% endif %}>
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    {{- form_label(form) -}}
    {{- form_errors(form) -}}
  </div>
{%- endblock form_row -%}
```

But all I get from my form when I try to render it is, "Variable "clearfix" does not exist in....."

So what have I done wrong? I guessing it has something to do with the service setup?

Thanks

---

ok, this is doing my head in a little, has I have gone over and over the docs but I am either doing it completely wrong or its what I want to do is just not do able?

So I am using Symfony 2.7, and have it setup to point to a forms twig file, so that I can override some of the defaults. This is working fine without any problems. However I now want to be able to render some of the rows with an added clearfix class. This is what I am rending right now,

```
{%- block form_row -%}
  <div>
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    {{- form_label(form) -}}
    {{- form_errors(form) -}}
  </div>
{%- endblock form_row -%}
```

That renders all my rows with the right classes, but I want to be able to use the following on some selected rows

```
{%- block _clerfix -%}
  <div class="clearfix">
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    {{- form_label(form) -}}
    {{- form_errors(form) -}}
  </div>
{%- endblock _clerfix -%}
```

And then I call this with the `block_name` within the Abstract Type of the form that I want to build with the added clearfix class, like so,

```
    ->add('password',   'password', ['label' => 'Password',
                                     'required' => false,
                                     'block_name' => 'clearfix',
                                     'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'off','class' => 'Passwordd', 'aria-required' => 'true' ]
                                    ])
```

Is what I want doable? I don't really want to add that clearfix into the user form I am building now, as that will not keep my code very DRY, as there will be (one would think so) places where I will need to re-use that block to render other fields?

All help most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're can create form extension for defining option to apply clearfix

**Symfony 2.8**

```
class ClearfixExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['clearfix'] = $options['clearfix'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefault('clearfix', false);
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }

}
```

services.yml

```
clearfix_extension:
    class: Bundle\Form\ClearfixExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType }
```

**Symfony 2.7**

```
class ClearfixExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['clearfix'] = $options['clearfix'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefault('clearfix', false);
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }

}
```

services.yml

```
clearfix_extension:
    class: Bundle\Form\ClearfixExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, alias: form }
```

and check this options in twig

```
{%- block form_row -%}
  <div {% if clearfix %}class="clearfix"{% endif %}>
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    {{- form_label(form) -}}
    {{- form_errors(form) -}}
  </div>
{%- endblock form_row -%}
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I have tried. I have a file that my config file points to and that loads the override, e.g. the 1st form block. However no matter what I do I can not get a single input field to render a different block, it just renders the 1st one. Therefore I dont get my clearfix class added to the wrapper div

Comment: That is NOT what I want to do, I want to be able to add a class block on selected inputs and NOT all checkbox, as in your example

Comment: Sorry, i update my answer. Now, i understood it correct?

Comment: Ok I sort of see how to do that, but I have to build a class for it? I like the way to edit the block. But the class seems a lot of work for something that should be very simple! Anyway, thanks, I give it a go when I can.

Comment: Also, you can use attr option - ['attr' => ['clearfix' => true]]
and check in template attr['clearfix'], but you need to remove this from attr array before form_widget, otherwise it be rendered as attribute. Example with extension better.

Comment: You done all correct.... for 2.8 :) I update my answer for 2.7. Actualize getExtendedType and service tag

Comment: Thanks mate, I give that ago when I get home!